# Export classified image from Google Earth Engine as tif

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export

Is it possible to export this classified [image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227384/exporting-a-classified-map-from-google-earth-engine) from Google Earth Engine (GEE)? I have seen similar [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227384/exporting-a-classified-map-from-google-earth-engine) but the difference is that I didn't produce that image. I tried to export it using this code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
      image: img_2019,
      description: 'imageToDriveExample',
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1000000000000,
      region: img_2019
    });
```

but I am getting a black raster. In their band description there exists 3 bands, named:

```
Band Description   
* lulc:  urban land use category   
* counts: the number of observations with the predicted lulc category   
* observations: the total number of observations
```

What I want is the first image of this [link](https://resourcewatch.org/data/explore/cit049-Urban-Land-Use-India_1?section=Discover&selectedCollection=&zoom=3&lat=20.566856033877922&lng=95.3237503676569&pitch=0&bearing=0&basemap=dark&labels=light&layers=%255B%257B%2522dataset%2522%253A%2522e354f7b8-0fca-422f-bf12-fc6189812bec%2522%252C%2522opacity%2522%253A1%252C%2522layer%2522%253A%25228efadc4d-7663-4666-ae69-fdf2dccd0cbd%2522%257D%255D&aoi=&page=1&sort=most-viewed&sortDirection=-1) (lulc: urban land use category).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was pretty straight forward. Basically, I just selected the desired band (lulc) from the `raster stack` by using the `.select('band')` . The whole code is here:

```
var img_2019 = ee.Image("projects/resource-watch-gee/cit_049_urban_land_use_India/India_2019_v2")
 .select('lulc')
 
var CAT_BAND='lulc';

var viz_params = {    
  bands: [CAT_BAND],    
  min: 0,    
  max: 6,    
  palette: ["6ADE6A","FF5E61","FD68FF","EDED87","0b60c8","00ffff","777777"],    
  opacity: 0.8
};


Map.addLayer(img_2019, viz_params, '2019 Urban Land Use India');

Map.setCenter(79.39, 22.82, 4);

Export.image.toDrive({
      image: img_2019,
      description: 'lulc',
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1000000000000,
      region: img_2019
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are supplying the image i.e. `img_2019` to the `region` parameter. In this, you should provide the extent polygon or the bounding coordinates of the area for which you want the data.

The documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive).

Comment: Regarding to the `region` parameter, the exported raster has black rectangle outside India but that can be easily removed by `clipping` the raster using any GIS (or other) software.